# Mongo DB mongoose schema.Save Function is Deleting Field From Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am Learning MongoDB Express To Build Api's. I am Building an API End Point To Reset Password, So To Update Password I use MongooseSchema.Save() Query For Running Validation Checks.

This is My Code Where I Update The Password.

```
  if (!user)
    return next(new AppError('Token is Invalid / Expired', 400));
  user.password = req.body.password;
  user.confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
  user.passwordResetToken = undefined;
  user.passwordResetExpires = undefined;
  user = await user.save();
  console.log(user);
  sendToken(user, 200, res);
```

The Query Succesfully Executes , and I also Recieve The Token at Response.
But When I check the password block in MongoDB Compass Application there is no Password Field and while Logging In It Shows That the password field is undefined.

So I logged the user as you can see in above code to check whether password is shown and it is present there. Everthing works fine just the password is deleted from the database.
This is my Console.log():

```
{ role: 'user',
  _id: 60db434647541f758fbe7357,
  name: 'Priyanshu Raturi',
  email: 'asffssf@gmail.com',
  password:
   '$2a$12$SijfMMslOO7i0P67f9KLruqrqEbtxb9ht7v/x9xoGw7U6QgwFPEMy',
  __v: 0 }
```

It was working fine earlier.

Comment: So is password in your user schema..?

Comment: Yes, it is even it is marked required.